# Android: stopping the thread while using Alert Dialog

Tags: android, multithreading, android-alertdialog

I have a program which first detects whether SD-card is present or not, if sd-card is not present, an alert dialog is presented which asks the user to retry or to exit. In short, sd-card is a must. However, in the case where there is no sd-card, the application continues working on the thread or the thread continues even after going the alert dialog part of my application. in short, what I want is that my application should wait for the alertdialog and get the input from the user.

Can anyone help me here.. thanks

Comment: Maybe some code will help understand your problem, cause right now I can't understand its architecture. It seems like you're doing some things wrong, but I can't tell what's wrong exactly since I don't see the code.

Comment: my application takes a list of videos stored on the sd card. just after starting onCreate method, I call another function that I made to check whether sd-card is mounted or not. if sd-card is not mounted, then show the alert dialog and asks the user to retry or exit. If user clicks retry, then the activity is recreated or if the user clicks exit, the activity is finished..

Comment: the problem here is that even if the control goes inside the if condition (if sd-card is unmounted) the background processing also goes which causes a crash because I am using so many things in the background like making directories in the external sd-card. it crashes because there is no sd-card. I want to the user to retry or exit whenever there is no sdcard and I want to stop the background processing as well.. is it possible??

Comment: Then you should call the SD card checking function first and then decide the further scenario based on the user's decision, whether to retry or to exit. You shouldn't do anything before you check the presence of SD card! If it's present - then go on.

Comment: actually sir, I need to call this sdcardchecking function in onResume method as well because my application is about playing videos. It may be possible that when the user gets back after playing the video, the sd-card is unmounted.. is there anyway that the current thread waits for the user to deal with the alertdialog rather than running background code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I dont completely understand your problem, I think following code will help you a little bit. It waits till OK clicked

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Please try again.").setPositiveButton("OK", dialogClickListener).show();
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            //OK  button clicked,  Add your code here

            break;


        }
    }
};
```

Edited: If you call alertBox from thread it will not work. You should call alertDialog from a UI thread
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                         @Override 
                         public void run() { 
                                                     } 
                     });`